# proving that a grammar is LL(1)

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, computer-science, regex-lookarounds

I'm given the following grammar :

```
S -> A a A b | B b B a
A -> epsilon
B -> epsilon
```

I know that it's obvious that it's LL(1), but I'm facing troubles constructing the parsing table.. I followed the algorithm word by word to find the first and follow of each non-terminal , correct me if I'm wrong:

```
First(S) = {a,b}
First(A) = First(B) = epsilon

Follow(S) = {$}
Follow(A) = {a,b}
Follow(B) = {a,b}
```

when I construct the parsing table, according to the algorithm, I get a conflict under the $ symbol... what the hell am I doing wrong??

```
     a       b      $
 A                   A-> epsilon
 B                   B-> epsilon
 S                   S -> AaAb
                     S -> BbBa
```

is it ok if I get 2 productions under $ or something?? or am I constructing the parsing table wrong? please help I'm new to the compiler course

Comment: Is this grammar LR(0)? And what about SLR(1)?

Answer (score 4):

There is a tiny mistake. Algorithm is as follows from dragon book,

```
for each rule (S -> A):
    for each terminal a in First(A):
        add (S -> A) to M[S, a]

    if First(A) contains empty:
        for each terminal b in Follow(S):
            add (S -> A) to M[S, b]
```

Let's take them one by one.

- `S -> AaAb`. Here, `First(AaAb) = {a}`. So add `S -> AaAb` to `M[S, a]`.
- `S -> BbBa`. Here, `First(BbBa) = {b}`. So add `S -> BbBa` to `M[S, b]`.
- `A -> epsilon`. Here, `Follow(A) = {a, b}`. So add `A -> epsilon` to `M[A, a]` and `M[A, b]`.
- `B -> epsilon`. Here, `Follow(B) = {a, b}`. So add `B -> epsilon` to `M[B, a]` and `M[B, b]`.